# Add a scrollbar to tooltip in "data-toggle"

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I have this piece of code that displays a tooltip when a user hovers over the question circle icon. The tooltip content can have a maximum character count of 1000. How do I set the overflow-y to scroll by modifying the tooltip in data-toggle mode?

```
&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@participant.DeclineReason" data-placement="bottom"></i>
```

I have the code for the data toggle in the JS script but how do I modify the tooltip properties:

```
@this.ScriptBlock(@<script>
    $(function (){
        $('.pie-chart').each(function () {
            $(this).pieChart({
                type: 'pie',
                barColor: getColor($(this).attr('data-percent')),
                trackColor: '#eee',
                lineCap: 'round',
                lineWidth: 5,
                rotate: 0,
                size: 145
            });

            $(this).find('.pie-chart__percentage').text($(this).data('percent') + '%');
        });

        $('.pie-chart-notparticipating').each(function () {
            $(this).pieChart({
                type: 'pie',
                barColor: getContrastColor($(this).attr('data-percent')),
                trackColor: '#eee',
                lineCap: 'round',
                lineWidth: 5,
                rotate: 0,
                size: 145,
                
            });

            $(this).find('.pie-chart__percentage').text($(this).data('percent') + '%');  
        });

        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  <-------------//this line here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `max-height` and `height` to a class

```
.tooltip{
   max-height:50px;
   height:100px;
   overflow-y:scroll;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t add a comment as I as I don’t have the rep, but a better solution would be to use `auto` rather than `scroll`.

```
.tooltip {
  max-height: 80px;
  overflow-y: auto; }
```

`auto` doesn’t show a scrollbar when the content doesn't need to scroll.